# Focus dropdown in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts

Hi I am kinda new to `JSP/Jquery/Javascript`. I'm studying struts right now. In my jsp file, I need to focus on a `drop-down list` onload of my page / everytime my page loads, I have done it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fault").focus();
    });
</script>
```

then in my `body`, im using the `html` tag:

```
    <body onload="makeDisableEnable()">

    <s:form>
    <div class="list">
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                <col style="width: 200px;">
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                <col>
                <col style="width: 120px;">
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody><tr>
            <th>DROPDOWN ONE<span class="font0">（※）</span></th>
                    <td><html:select property="failCnd" styleId="fault">
                    <html:option value=""></html:option>
                    <c:forEach var="failCnd" items="${failCndList}">
                    <html:option value="${failCnd.wideUseCd}">${f:h(failCnd.wideUseValueView)}</html:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </html:select>
                </td>
```

This is what I have done but its not working. Could anyone tell me what I have done wrong? Or what are other ways. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try the code below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fault").focus();
    });
 </script>
```

HTML CODE

```
 <body onload="makeDisableEnable()">
```

to

```
 <body>
```

Check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTHwW/)

NEW EDITED [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ShhH/)

Comment: i need the makeDisableEnable method.

Comment: just try without makeDisableEnable method.and then check its working or not,If it is working than apply your makeDisableEnable method

Comment: have your check fiddle link

Comment: Yes i have seen the fiddle link. but it isnt working. its supposed to be focused in the dropdown. but it doesnt.

Comment: which browser you are checking , check it in chrome

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22095/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-superman)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `<body onload="...">` breaks jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the < body
>   onload="" > attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready()
>   or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the
>   window or to more specific items, like images.

You could just move `makeDisableEnable()` into the jQuery "ready" block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fault").focus();
        makeDisableEnable();
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what `makeDisableEnable()` does, so feel free to move it before `$("#fault").focus();` if it makes more sense.

Comment: okay, so if its breaks jQuery, can I use a method the same as above but in javascript? Because i have tried but its not working also.

Comment: I think I cannot understand what you mean. What I'm saying is that your "onload" handler prevents the one of jQuery from working. Please try moving makeDisableEnable() into the jQuery "ready" block: jQuery instructions are just JavaScript, you can mix them.

Comment: My makeDisableEnable() method is a javascript for disabling my dropdown. So I just move the whole javascript method in my .ready part?

Comment: In which way it doesn't work? What does javascript console say? Just trying to help :)

Comment: It doesnt produce the focus part. I dont know about the javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to html5, there is an autofocus attribute.

Try:

```
<html:select property="failCnd" styleId="fault" autofocus="autofocus">
```

[HTML 5 AutoFocus](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_autofocus.asp)

Comment: it says `"Autofocus" Undefined attribute name`

Comment: That's because you're not using bare HTML tags, you're using struts **server-side** tag libraries, which probably neglect that attribute.